# Mongoose querying data that needs populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Mongoose model that is pretty simple:

```
aclSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    public_read: Boolean,
    public_write: Boolean,
});
aclModel = mongoose.model('acl', aclSchema);
```

And another model that references it:

```
thingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    _acl: { type: String, ref: 'acl' }
});
thingModel = mongoose.model('thing', thingSchema);
```

I need to be able to find documents ( thingModel ) where _acl.public_read is true. The problem i'm having is that since thing._acl is a ref, it's not populated until after the querying is done.

example:

```
thingModel.find({"_acl.public_read":true}).populate('_acl').exec(callback);
```

That returns no results because, I guess, _acl is a ref and it's not populated until after the find returns documents.

Just a side note, the schema's are more complicated than this and have other ref's in them that could be circular. I have not included them for simplicity sake, but the basic idea is there. If it was really this simple, i would use sub-documents and it would all work as expected.

Is there a better way to do this so I get the expected documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do it in Mongo 3.2 using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

`$lookup` takes four arguments

`from`:     Specifies the collection in the same database to perform the join with. The from collection cannot be sharded.

`localField`: Specifies the field from the documents input to the $lookup stage. $lookup performs an equality match on the localField to the foreignField from the documents of the from collection.

`foreignField`: Specifies the field from the documents in the from collection.

`as`: Specifies the name of the new array field to add to the input documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from the from collection.

```
thingModel.aggregate([{

  $lookup: {
     from: 'aclCollection',
     localField: '_acl',
     foreignField: '_id',
     as : 'acl'
  },
  {$unwind: '$acl'},
  {$match:{"acl.public_read":true }}
], callback);
```

In case of populate, it is not possible directly. Refer to similar question
[Mongoose nested query on Model by field of its referenced model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380738/mongoose-nested-query-on-model-by-field-of-its-referenced-model)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Any known way to do it in < 3.2?

Comment: @Alex answer updated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380738/mongoose-nested-query-on-model-by-field-of-its-referenced-model